# Gerber and silkscreen

Tags: pcb-fabrication, gerber

I have a question regarding PCB manufacturing process and gerber files:

if a made a change only on the silkscreen layer, can I send only this layer to the PCB manufacturer ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking this question from your PCB manufacturer? Only they can answer to that how they want the changes from you.

Comment: NEVER NEVER NEVER submit incomplete or piecemeal gerbers.  You're asking for trouble.  You can change a single layer, send the WHOLE PACKAGE.  Your PC manufacturer may or may not be able to catch that stage of the process if you ask nicely.   Silk is one of the last processing steps.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is best to send all files in one zip folder. Many low-cost manufacturers from China work on low margins and have high work loads, so it is best to provide all files.